# Elasticsearch.js - wait for ping to complete, async call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, elasticsearch

I am playing with elasticsearch.js from the browser. I would like to ping elasticsearch, wait for the request to complete and then return the result of the connection. But right now it is happening asynchronously, and returning `undefined` even when the connection is ok. I have code like this:

```
var connectionOK = false;

function createElasticsearchClient(hostAddress) {
    var client = new $.es.Client({
        hosts: hostAddress
    });
    return client;
}

function checkElasticsearchConnection(client) {
    $.when(pingElasticsearch(client)).done(function () {
        return connectionOK;
    });
}

function pingElasticsearch(client) {
    console.log("ELASTICSEARCH: Trying to ping es");
    client.ping({
        requestTimeout: 30000,

        // undocumented params are appended to the query string
        hello: "elasticsearch"
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('ELASTICSEARCH: Cluster is down!');
            connectionOK = false;
            console.log("INSIDE: " + connectionOK);
        } else {
            console.log('ELASTICSEARCH: OK');
            connectionOK = true;
            console.log("INSIDE: " + connectionOK);
        }
    });
}
```

and how it is used:

```
var esClient = createElasticsearchClient("exampleserver.com:9200");
var esCanConnect = (checkElasticsearchConnection(esClient));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing asynchronous functions with synchronous functions. You could go with this approach instead:

```
function createElasticsearchClient(hostAddress, callback) {
    var client = new $.es.Client({
        hosts: hostAddress
    });
    return callback(client);
}

function pingElasticsearch(client, callback) {
    console.log("ELASTICSEARCH: Trying to ping es");
    client.ping({
        requestTimeout: 30000,

        // undocumented params are appended to the query string
        hello: "elasticsearch"
    }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          return callback('ELASTICSEARCH: Cluster is down!');
        } else {
            return callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

And then run

```
createElasticsearchClient("exampleserver.com:9200", function(esClient) {
  pingElasticsearch(esClient, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
      //Everything is ok
      console.log('All good');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey @jpiechowka if my answer helped you, can you accept the answer?